# Erlang - конфигурационный фаил

Tags: erlang, configuration

В своем проекте, кроме app.src, я хочу использовать конфигурационный фаил который я буду хранить не в папке проекта, а в домашней дириктории.
Я пробовал добавить флаг `-config ~/.my_app.config` при запуске, но это не принесло желаемого результата - `application:get_env/2` возвращает `undefined` при попытке извлечения значение нужного параметра, который определен в ~/.my_app.config

Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно добавляю секцию relx в rebar.config file

```
{relx, [
{mkdir, "log"},
{release, {"test_app", "1.0.0"}, [test_app]},
{vm_args, "config/vm.args"},
{sys_config, "config/sys.config"},
{include_erts, true},
{extended_start_script, true}
]}.
```

И соответственно кладу sys.config в папку config/

Answer (score 0):

**my.config**

```
[
  {myapp, [
    {param1, "hello"}
  ]}
].
```

Нужно загрузить приложение.

```
erl -config ~/my.config
Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.0.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Eshell V13.0.4  (abort with ^G)
1> application:get_env(myapp, param1).
undefined
2> application:ensure_all_started(myapp).
{ok,[myapp]}
3> application:get_env(myapp, param1).
{ok,"hello"}
4>
```